# Django rest framework write / update nested serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to write and update nested serializer in drf.
I have two models. Just an example below.

```
Class Account (AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True
```

```
Class USerProfile(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

already have an `AccountSerilaizer` for Registration view

```
class AccountSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    confirm_password = CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "password", "confirm_password"]
        extra_kwargs = {
            "password": {"write_only": True},
        }

    def validate_email(self, value):
        qs = Account.objects.filter(email__iexact=value)
        if qs.exists():
            raise ValidationError("Email already exists")
        return value

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs.get("first_name") == "" or attrs.get("last_name") == "":
            raise ValidationError("Names cannot be blank")
        return attrs

    def validate_password(self, data):
        if len(data) < 8:
            raise ValidationError(
                "Password should be atleast 8 digits or characters or letters"
            )
        return data

    def validate(self, data):
        if data["password"] != data.pop("confirm_password"):
            raise ValidationError({"error": "Passwords donot match"})
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = Account.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get("first_name", instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get("last_name", instance.last_name)
        instance.email = validated_data.get("email", instance.email)

        instance.save()
        return instance
```

So `UserProfile` is FK to `Account`, how to update/write `UserProfile` and how to get `request.user` inside serializer during `create/update` method and I'm using JWT Authentication. There is a third party package I came to know to write nested serializer, but i want to know how to do wihtout it.

EDIT:
I have managed to create it but there is one thing i need to be clear that is i have given `required=False` in `user = AccountSerializer(required=False)` then only the create method works otherwise I'm getting

```
user : [
    "This field is required"
   ]
```

UserProfile serializer is given below:

```
class UserprofileSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    user = AccountSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = [
            "user",
            "address_line_1",
            "address_line_2",
            "city",
            "state",
            "country",
            "gender",
            "phone",
            "date_of_birth",
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context["user"]
        print(user)
        user_profile =UserProfile.objects.create(user=user,            **validated_data)

        return user_profile
```

Comment: It looks like a lot of what you are doing in your serializer can be achieved by setting the appropriate attributes on the fields.  Is there a reason you need to do this in the serializer?

Comment: Also, I would move most of this logic to the view/viewset where you are closer to the request.

Comment: Can you post your required output format

Comment: @monkut why did you say you move most of the logic to the view?

Comment: That's they way I've been doing it.  Also, you have direct access to the request, so you can get the user info without additional hoops to jump through.

Comment: But we have to write additonal validation for the data right if its in the views?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever u deal with a user field where u need to get the logged in user u can user `CurrentUserDefault` on the serializer. One more thing user on the create method is not getting the user from the data from the AccountSerializer. it is getting it from request.

If u want to create and validate the user using the user profile then do this

```
class UserprofileSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    user = AccountSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = [
            "user",
            "address_line_1",
            "address_line_2",
            "city",
            "state",
            "country",
            "gender",
            "phone",
            "date_of_birth",
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user_serializer = AccountSerializer("user")
        user_serilializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True)
        user = user_serilizer.save()
        user_profile =UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)

        return user_profile
```

otherwise

```
class UserprofileSerializer(...):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField( 
         default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
)
```

documentation on `CurrentUserDefault` is [here.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault)

Comment: Hey thanks for reply, I'll check it out. And what is the correct way of writing nested serializer, do I have to create userprofile in `AccountSerializer` create method or the way I did. Created `User` in `UserProfileSerializer`. I think you understand my doubt?